# Different HTML element selection for wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select mutiple different html elements and wrap them all with div ?

In example:

```
<span contenteditable="false">The correct answer is (A) 1 to 2. </span> <span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice B (2 to 3) </span><span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice C (3 to 4) </span><span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice D (4 to 5) </span><span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice E (5 to 6) </span><span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
```

Can I and how to select these elements? Any ideas?

Tried JQuery's wrapAll, but it won't take 
 elements, if I would select by class name..

Comment: `.wrapAll()` should work. share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `siblings()` can be used to select all the siblings of one element. Then do `wrapAll()`

```js
var $div = $('<div>');
$('span[contenteditable]')
    .first()
    .nextUntil('span:not([contenteditable])')
    .addBack()
    .wrapAll( $div );
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span contenteditable="false">The correct answer is (A) 1 to 2. </span> 
<span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice B (2 to 3) </span>
<span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice C (3 to 4) </span>
<span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice D (4 to 5) </span>
<span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span contenteditable="false">Choice E (5 to 6) </span>
<span contenteditable="true" class="answers-edit"></span>
<br>
<span>I don't need this to be wrapped!</span>
```

Comment: @RudolfsJanitis In that case you need something unique to be able to select what kind of elements are not intended to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That is possible.
Example

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>cruel</p>
<p>World</p>

<script>
$( "p" ).wrapAll( "<div></div>" );
</script>
```

Comment: If there will be <br> elements between, then these willl be ignored. They ar pretty important in this case.